# sqlplus not connecting as "/ AS SYSDBA"

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I installed oracle database express edition 18c. I'm using windows 10.

when I execute "/ AS SYSDBA" in sqlplus to user-name, it gives the following error.

> ERROR:
> ORA-28056: Writing audit records to Windows Event Log failed
> ORA-28056: Writing audit records to Windows Event Log failed

when I execute below

```
Enter user-name: SYS AS SYSDBA
Enter password: <password I gave on installation>
```

it prints below error

> ERROR: 
> ORA-28056: Writing audit records to Windows Event Log failed 
> OSD-32765: Message 32765 not found;  product=RDBMS; facility=SOSD 
> O/S-Error: (OS 5) Access is denied. 
> ORA-28056: Writing audit records to Windows Event Log failed 
> OSD-32765: Message 32765 not found;  product=RDBMS; facility=SOSD 
> O/S-Error: (OS 5) Access is denied.

when I try to execute below

```
Enter user-name: SYSTEM
Enter password: <password I gave on installation>
```

it prints below error

> ERROR: 
>  ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
>  ORA-27101: shared
> memory realm does not exist 
>  Process ID: 0 
>  Session ID: 0
> Serial number: 0

So how can I connect to the database?

Note: I cleared all the event logs from event viewer. not worked!!

Additionally by default there are no environment variable set. so I set

```
set ORACLE_HOME=C:\app\user\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE
set ORACLE_SID=CLRExtProc
```

After setting above it provides below error

> ERROR: 
> ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

so please help me to connect to database

Thank you!!!

Comment: _"set ORACLE_SID=CLRExtProc"_  Most assuredly not the correct value.  You installed express edition, so your ORACLE_SID is XE.

Comment: changed to set ORACLE_SID=XE. Still getting same error

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have not configured properly the `sqlnet.ora` file

Try to run this

```
C:\>sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL*Plus: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Aug 26 15:49:17 2020
Version 18.4.0.0.0
Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle. All rights reserved.
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

If you get this error, then open the `SQLNET.ORA` file and edit the following parameter `AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES` value to `NTS`. Save it.

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NONE)
to
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)
```

Try again and it should work, as long as the windows service is running. Don't forget to set the `ORACLE_SID` environment variable

```
set ORACLE_SID=sid
```

Where `sid` is the name of the database you want to connect to. Finally

```
C:\>sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL*Plus: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Aug 26 15:49:34 2020
Version 18.4.0.0.0
Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle. All rights reserved.
Connected to:
Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.4.0.0.0
SQL>
```

**Update**

The database can't write into the Windows Event Log.

1. Open Event Viewer, click Start, click Control Panel, click Performance and Maintenance, click Administrative Tools, and then double-click Event Viewer. *You must be logged on as an administrator or a member of the Administrators group to free an event log.*
2. Then use any of the next options:

When a log is full, it stops recording new events. Clearing the log is one way to free the log and start recording new events. You can also free a log and start recording new events by overwriting old events. To overwrite events, on the Action menu, click Properties, and then click Overwrite events as needed. This ensures that all new events are written to the log, even when the log is full.

You can also start logging new events by increasing the maximum log size. To increase the log size, on the Action menu, click Properties, and then increase the Maximum log size.

Comment: SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS) its already there. still not connecting

Comment: is the Oracle service running ?

Comment: yes when I check services oracleXE is running

Comment: it looks like the user owner of the oracle software has no privileges to write in the audit file. Do you install Oracle with an administrator user ?

Comment: I updated the answer, probably the event log is full

Comment: I cleared all logs in event viewer (application, system, security). still having the same error. I hope something preventing me to get connected... yes I installed and running as administrator

Answer (score 0):

Verify permissions of sqlplus

```
ls -l $ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus
```

[image]

As per the attached result, I had to run sqlplus from oracle user

```
su - oracle
```