# Oracle sqlplus / as sysdba not work in Windows Server 2016

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I recreated oracle database again on my windows machine. However i can not connect sqlplus / as sysdba. it gives TNS-12560 error. However i can connect with sqlplus /@mysid as sysdba.

The service is working.
And I see Registry keys are entered.
lsnrctl status works and i can see my services are OK.
on cmd, I set ORACLE_SID=mysid

What should i do more?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69395041/sqlplus-not-connecting-as-as-sysdba?rq=1

Comment: The syntax 'sqlplus / as sysdba' asks for a local connection to the instance identified by the value of the environment variable ORACLE_SID.  (Being a local connection, the listener doesn't even come into play).  TNS-12560 - TNS Protocl Adapter Error is invariably due to not having ORACLE_SID correctly set.

Comment: What do you mean you "recreated oracle database again"?  How many times have you tried to recreate it?  Why?  Exactly what step did you take to "recreate" it?

Comment: Before posting a question or while posting a question, you might be able to find a solution to your problem by going through already existing contents on Stackoverflow. For instance, you could go through this post before posting the question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894558/ora-12560-tnsprotocol-adaptor-error